# How to perform a Reverse Animation Using Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have start doing animations in web recently using Framer Motion. I was wondering how can I make it work in reverse. In my case, I have a Modal which animates from positive X-aixs to 0 Position on X-axis, when animation is completed.

I want it go off the screen in a same way as it entered the screen.

Here's the code

```
    const variants = {
        hidden: { x: 400, transition: { duration: 0.3 } },
        visible: { x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.3 } },
    };

    return(
        <motion.section
        animate='visible'
        initial='hidden'
        variants={variants}
        className='container'
        >...
       </motion.section>
    )
```

here is the link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-brook-rh8txh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: So just animate it back to `hidden`? What is the problem exactly? Would be great if you could make a minimal reproduction on https://codesandbox.io

Comment: okay I have made a sandbox and edited the question